# Characters(Syllables) are not rendered in correct order in pillow

Tags: python, text, python-imaging-library

I am trying to print Burmese characters(Myanmar3.ttf to be precise) on images for data generation-OCR. Unlike other languages, in Burmese language, word/character is constructed using syllables and there is order in syllables. Therefore, unicode for Burmese language uses complex text ordering. When I print the characters on image, the syllables doesn't combine together to form a word.
Here's some reference to Burmese language:
http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/30/collation/my.html

Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw

img = Image.open("BG.png")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("Myanmar3.ttf", 13)
draw.text((0, 0), u"ကြည့်ရှုခွင့်ရသူ", (0, 0, 0), font = unicode_font)
img.save("sample1.png")
```

The way it should appear:
[Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlHvE.png)

The way it shouldn't appear:
[False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNEjb.png)

Comment: What is your Pillow version? Which platform do you use?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer OS: Windows 10, Pillow version: 5.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pillow does not support complex script rendering if the [libraqm](https://github.com/HOST-Oman/libraqm) library is not installed.  On Debian, you can try installing `libraqm0`:

```bash
# apt install libraqm0
```

It improves the rendering for me.

Comment: I saw that libraqm is also built upon pillow and cairo. Does libraqm support multiple font styles like pillow? Because I want to multiply the amount of training data by using various kind of font styles.